# I payed a magazine company for a blog post and photo shoot was done but now they want to send me 3.4k. I payed 160 for pics with mag and 300 to pub

Tags: check

I payed a magazine company for a blog post and photo shoot was done but now they want to send me 3.4k. I payed 160 for pics with mag and 300 to publish idk if its real or fake kinda hesitant

Comment: What are you asking though? Is there a question here?

Comment: It also isn't clear what you bought, or thought you were buying, with your $460. Were you buying a blog post (why?) or were they? Did they do a photo shoot or did you? What magazine was this, are they legitimate, and have you contacted them directly to find out if you're really doing business with the magazine as opposed to someone who claims to be them?

Comment: If they want to send you money, it is a scam.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any time someone wants you to pay in order to be published, it's a scam, or at best a "vanity press". There are a few contests that have entry fees, and there are print-on-demand publishers that have set-up fees, but even these should be approached with caution since you are extremely unlikely to earn that money back unless you have something exceptional.

Any time someone wants you to pay them in order to receive money, or asks you to pass part of an overpayment along to someone else, or wants your login credentials, it's a scam.

In general, if you have any suspicion that it is a scam, you are probably correct.

Comment: Expanding upon your "almost any time," one notable exception is open access journals, which turn the publishing business model on its head. For example, Elsevier, a reputable publisher, [charges authors or their institutions](https://www.elsevier.com/open-access/open-access-journals) several hundred to several thousand dollars to cover the publication costs. Ditto [SpringerOpen](https://www.springeropen.com/about/open-access), the open-access arm of Springer.

Comment: Yeah, but "blog post" and "photo shoot" suggest this isn't anything remotely that respectable.

Comment: True, but I was responding to "Almost any time someone wants you to pay in order to be published." Maybe "Outside of open-access journal-land, ..."?

Comment: But per the OP, they (the magazine) are sending the OP the money? Unclear...

Comment: There are many scams involving "we want to send you money but need to do it this way" where the victim winds up paying rather than being paid. If you don't know why someone wants to pay you, or if the amount seems unreasonable, or if the way they want to do it is at all odd, assume it's a scam.

Comment: Re "outside open-accrss journals" -- there are exceptions. We can't enumerate them all here. But generally the people dealing with those know exactly why they are exceptions and can recognize them as such. I admit I could weaken "any time" to "almost any time", but I'd rather have folks start appropriately cautious than have them start thinking "I can't understand it but maybe it's all right." Sometimes paranoia is not enough.

Comment: (Actually, it looks like I did say "Almost" in my original post. No correction needed.)